# Scrolling prints a bunch of A or B's in insert mode

Tags: scrolling

A bunch of A or B's gets printed on the screen when I accidentally scroll with the touchpad in `insert` mode.

What can I do to prevent such an annoying behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

**It's because there is `set noesckeys` in your `.vimrc`.**

**Removing this line in your `.vimrc` should solve the problem.**

If the reason behind this parameter was because some commands such
as `O` are too slow and someone recommended it as a tip, you can instead `set ttimeout` and `set ttimeoutlen=50` instead.

(Tip: If you also want scrolling to be disabled in insert mode, you can `inoremap <Up> <Nop>` and `inoremap <Down> <Nop>`. Note that when `noesckeys` is set, mapping `<Up>` or `<Down>` won't work)

**If you really need this parameter**, you can map the escape sequences sent by the up and down arrow to `<Nop>`.
An escape sequence is a sequence of values that are used to control the terminal (move cursor, clear terminal, etc.).
In order to see what escape sequences correspond to the arrows, put yourself in insert mode, press `ctrl + v` and then the up or down arrow.
You should see something like `^]OA` or `^]OB`. `^` is Vim representation of the value sent by `Esc`, together with `]` they get the terminal attention, and then O and A instruct to move the cursor up.
So you can map the following :

```
inoremap <esc>0A <Nop>                                                         
inoremap <esc>OB <Nop>
```

Thanks to all the great people on freenode's `#vim` that helped me.